# Mount android device 4.0.4 on linux

Tags: arch-linux, usb, usb-drive, android, mtp

I am trying to mount a Samsung Galaxy S2 as a mass storage device onto an uptodate Arch Linux setup.

On the Android phone I have done the following

Settings -> More -> USB Utilities -> USB mass storage

Then I followed the instructions and it seems to have successfully entered mass storage mode.

On Arch system if run `dmesg` I get the following new entries:

```
[16309.075881] usb 3-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
```

If I run `lsusb` I get:

```
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 04e8:685b Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (mass storage mode)
```

Finally if I run `Journalctl` I get:

```
Jan 23 00:33:19 floyd kernel: usb 3-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Jan 23 00:33:19 floyd mtp-probe[30020]: checking bus 3, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1"
Jan 23 00:33:19 floyd mtp-probe[30020]: bus: 3, device: 14 was not an MTP device
```

But how do I actually mount this device?

I've read a lot about using MTP which look rather long winded, is there not a plug-and-play way of mounting this and accessing it like USB drive like I was with older Android devices.

Thanks in advance.